# How to "reset" the .replaceWith function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, replacewith

How do I "reset" the .replaceWith function so that the html, css and javascript are returned back to their original state?

The idea is to have an icon replace the text when the user clicks on "contact", and when the user clicks on "back" button, the icon returns back to the "contact" text. Right now, the icon switches back to text, but the text isn't responsive when I try to repeat the function a second time.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="contact">Contact</div>
<button class="back">Back</button>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var contactswitch = $('<div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div>');
var switchback = $('.contact');

  $('.contact').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(contactswitch)
  });

  $('.back').click(function() {
    $(contactswitch).replaceWith(switchback)
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Save the old DOM elements in a variable before you replace them.

Comment: Save the content in a variable before replacing. Or add another element and "replace" by toggling visibility.

Comment: Why replace? Toggle visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-assign the click handler on the back button click:

```
  $('.back').click(function() {
    switchback.click(function() { $(this).replaceWith(contactswitch);});
    $(contactswitch).replaceWith(switchback)
  });
```